# Optimizing SQL INSERT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, t-sql, sql-insert

I have recently been looking into possible ways how to optimize my INSERT queries. I am doing usually an INSERT with a batch size of 100.

My current example query:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM [db].[Prices] WHERE Source = 'Cars' AND TradeDate = convert(datetime,'18-02-20',5) AND Product = 'Audi' AND Price=NULLIF('5.00000',''))

BEGIN DELETE FROM [db].[Prices] WHERE Source = 'Cars' AND TradeDate = convert(datetime,'18-02-20',5) AND Product = 'Audi' AND Price=NULLIF('5.00000','') END;

INSERT INTO [db].[Prices] VALUES( 'Cars', convert(datetime,'18-02-20',5), 'APR25', NULL, 'Audi', NULLIF('5.00000',''), convert(datetime,'15-04-25',5), '1', GETUTCDATE(), convert(date,NULL,105), convert(date,NULL,105));
```

The possible optimizations that I have found from research are as following:

- Replace * with fields
- Replace WHERE with INNER JOIN

As this is rather new to me, any suggestions are welcome. It seems like the highest potential is in changing the core structure (IF EXISTS - DELETE - INSERT INTO).

Thank you for any help.

Comment: 2 digit years? NO NO NO NO NO! There is no excuse for this 20 years after Y2k!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`EXISTS` will not necessary here you can use `DELETE` statement :

```
 DELETE 
 FROM [db].[Prices] 
 WHERE Source = 'Cars' AND TradeDate = CONVERT(DATETIME,'18-02-20', 5) AND 
       Contract = 'APR25' AND ProductCode = 'Audi' AND 
       Price = NULLIF('5.00000','') -- this will always 5.00000 `NULLIF` will not required
       AND Strike = '27.7500';
```

Then you can use `INSERT` Statement :

```
INSERT INTO [db].[Prices] (col1, col2, col3, . . .) -- Qualify all columns
    VALUES( 'Cars', convert(datetime,'18-02-20',5), 'APR25', NULL, 'Audi',
             NULLIF('5.00000',''), convert(datetime,'15-04-25',5), '1', 
             GETUTCDATE(), convert(date,NULL,105), 
             convert(date,NULL,105), 04, 2025, NULL, NULL, '27.7500', '20', 
             NULL, '0.5',NULL
          );
```

You can remove `nullif()` & conversation style in `where` clause :

```
WHERE Source = 'Cars' AND TradeDate = '2020-02-18' AND 
      Contract = 'APR25' AND ProductCode = 'Audi' AND 
      Price = 5.00000 AND Strike = '27.7500';
```

You might need `NULLIF()` on `Price` :

```
NULLIF(Price, '')
```

Note : Always qualify *all* columns explicitly while using `INSERT INTO . .` statement.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using MERGE statement. Instead of DELETE followed by INSERT, you can do UPDATE / INSERT:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql